# How can I make multiple views render in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code, but it is not correct to render five times in one controller, how can I get best result for this ?

```
public static function index($path,$data,$data_nav,$data_content)
{
    $view=view($path.'.preheader_view',$data)->render();
    $view.=view($path.'.header_view')->render();
    $view.=view($path.'.main_navigation_view',$data_nav)->render();
    $view.=view($path.'.main_content_view',$data_content)->render();
    $view.=view($path.'.main_aside_view',$data)->render();
    $view.=view($path.'.footer_view',$data)->render();
    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever hear about blade? It's a templating engine in which you can extend and include templates. This seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks But think I am not ready for the blade just want to know how Laravel can make it in controller

Comment: Do you happen to be coming from codeigniter? This is how you do it in that framework but it's the wrong way to do it in Laravel. Look at [Blade layout templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#defining-a-layout) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using native Laravel [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) templates.

You'll be able to make includes, extends, yields, etc.

Eg:

app.blade.php

```
<html>
@yield('content')
</html>
```

example.blade.php

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
Here is your content, with some {{$variables}}
@endsection
```

In your controller

```
public function method() {
    ...
    return view('example')->with(['variables'=>'VARIABLE TEXT']);

    //example refers to example.blade.php
    //eg: yourpage refers to yourpage.blade.php
    //with subdirectories: foo.bar refers to foo/bar.blade.php
}
```